# HTML and Javascript; I want to repeat my form results in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I know I am probably doing this in the least elegant way possible but I'm still a beginner. I want to generate a user form where people input variables. On the click of a button those variables appear in the proper place in a paragraph (Ex.. name, Date). I put together some pieces from code that copies text from one box to another... now I want to create a paragraph below where the variables populate in the middle of the relevant sentence.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title>textBoxes.html</title>
 <script type = "text/javascript">


  function sayHi(){
  // THIS is WHERE input VARIABLES are set, followed by the OUTPUT
  //this defines the First Week of Sickness Paid Start Date
  var BPCName = document.getElementById("BPCName");
  var OUTBPC = document.getElementById("OUTBPC");
  var name = BPCName.value;
  OUTBPC.value = " " +name+ ""
  //This defines the last week of Sickness Benefits Paid
    var LWPName = document.getElementById("LWPName");
  var OUTLWP = document.getElementById("OUTLWP");
  var name = LWPName.value;
  OUTLWP.value = " " +name+ ""
  //This defines Total Weeks of Sickness Benefits Paid
  var TWSPName = document.getElementById("TWSPName");
   var OUTTWSP = document.getElementById("OUTTWSP");
  var name = TWSPName.value;
  OUTTWSP.value = " " +name+ ""
  // This Defines the Date the Medical Was received
  var MEDRName = document.getElementById("MEDRName");
   var OUTMEDR = document.getElementById("OUTMEDR");
  var name = MEDRName.value;
 OUTMEDR.value = " " +name+ ""
//This Defines the Medical Provider
  var MEDPName = document.getElementById("MEDPName");
  var OUTMEDP = document.getElementById("OUTMEDP");
  var name = MEDPName.value;
  OUTMEDP.value = " " +name+ ""
 // THis Defines the Date of Incapacity indicated on the Medical
  var INCName = document.getElementById("INCName");
  var OUTINC = document.getElementById("OUTINC");
  var name = INCName.value;
  OUTINC.value = " " +name+ ""

  } // end sayHi
 </script>
 <link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "textBoxes.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Automatic</h1>
 <form action = "">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Start Date: </label>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "BPCName" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "click me"
    onclick = "sayHi()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "OUTBPC" />
  </fieldset>
 </form> 

  <form action = "">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Last Week of Benefits Paid: </label>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "LWPName" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "click me"
    onclick = "sayHi()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "OUTLWP" />
  </fieldset>

      <form action = "">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Total Weeks of Sickness Benefits Paid: </label>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "TWSPName" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "click me"
    onclick = "sayHi()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "OUTTWSP" />

          <form action = "">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Date Medical Received: </label>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "MEDRName" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "click me"
    onclick = "sayHi()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "OUTMEDR" />
            <form action = "">

  <fieldset>
  <label>Name of Practitioner: </label>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "MEDPName" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "click me"
    onclick = "sayHi()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "OUTMEDP" /> 
      <form action = "">

  <fieldset>
  <label>Date of Incapacity Indicated on Medical: </label>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "INCName" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "click me"
    onclick = "sayHi()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "OUTINC" /> 
      <form action = "">
  </fieldset>
 </form>  

  <h2> Example Document</h2>

  <p>The client was sent an EForm form requesting submission of original medical to confirm eligibility for benefits. 
The client was paid  XXXXX weeks of benefits during the period XXXX to XXXXX

The client submitted an original doctor’s note signed by XXXX dated XXX
Claimant notified in writing that claim is on order.
The medical addresses all weeks in which sickness benefits were paid.
</P>
</html>
```

Comment: explain with  an example plz

Comment: are you looking for substituting user input to paragraph at the last of your code?

Comment: That's correct. I want the inputs to appear in the paragraph @ the end of the code

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using jQuery and a regular expression:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Replace example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="text">Hello, my name is {{ name }}.</p>
    <p>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="name" value="Sally">
        </form>
        <button id="name-button">Replace</button>
    </p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Replace {{ name }} when the user clicks the button
        $('#name-button').click(function() {
            var currentText = $('#text').html();
            var name = $('#name').val();
            var newText = currentText.replace(/{{ name }}/, name)
            $('#text').html(newText);
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jb88tsxe/).

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Joseph.. it is the way to do it in Jquery. But that suggested solution replaces one pattern at a time, which means you will have to click the button again to replace the other string with same pattern(if you have one).

Its like: (Using Joseph's code to demonstrate)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Replace example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="text">Hello, my last name is {{ name }}. Also my father's last name is {{ name }}.</p> <!-- Don't mind the sentence -->
    <p>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="name" value="Sally">
        </form>
        <button id="name-button">Replace</button>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

All you got to do is search them globally which can be done by passing global flag that is `/g`. So the Jquery becomes:

`var newText = currentText.replace(/{{ name }}/g, name)`

Everything is same as Joseph's just a little modified.

Comment: Thank you so much. My only problem now is that I can't get 'code' $('#name-button').on('click',function() { to work

Comment: have you put it inside document.ready? It will be something like $(document).ready(function() {  $('#name-button').on('click',function() {}); });